# How to replace ListView with GroupedListView while using StreamBuilder with FireBase data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, stream-builder

This is my **ListView**. It works perfectly:

```
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = streamSnapshot.data!
                    .docs[index];
                return Card(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(documentSnapshot['name'] + " (" +
                        documentSnapshot['quantity'].toStringAsFixed(0) + ")"),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }

          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );

        }
      ),
```

I use a StreamBuilder to obtain data from FireBase.  I turn that stream into snapshots, which are used inside the builder part of the ListView.

**How do I replace my ListView with a GroupedListView?**

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent **GroupedListView**:

```
      StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
            if (!streamSnapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
            return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(

              elements: streamSnapshot.data!.docs,

              groupBy: (element) => element['category'],
              groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  value,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
              floatingHeader: true,
              order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,

              itemComparator: (item1, item2) => item1['name'].compareTo(item2['name']),
              itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) {
                return Card(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(element['name']),
                  ),
                );
              },

            );
          }
      ),
```